# UWP get bytes or pixels from BitmapImage

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, bitmap, bitmapimage

I have to make parallel work (of course async Task) that blur images selected from folder, so I have found this (BitmapImage), but the problem is what i do not know how to access bytes or pixels of this object, so that I can change them, blur or something else:

```
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

            var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            var filesList = await folder.GetFilesAsync();



            for (int i = 0; i < filesList.Count; i++)
            {
                using (var stream = await filesList[i].OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
//Here I will use some array of BitmapImage 
                    var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);

                    //show Image on Form
                    imageSourceForm.Source = bitmapImage;
                }

            }
```

So is there any way to get pixels or bytes of this object, or maybe do you know what to use that I can do work, but with async Task. The most important part is that UI Thread has to be responsive, while the images are blurring. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code to get bytes of an image:

```
var random = await Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(filesList[i]).OpenReadAsync();
Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
Windows.Graphics.Imaging.PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();

//Access pixel buffer in such a way
byte[] bytes = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
```